# Symfony Migrations Bundle creating the same migration over and over again

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-cli

I added an auto-update timestamp to an entity like in [this blog post](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2022/01/11/orm-2.11.html) and it works just fine.

Here is the code snippet:

```php
#[Entity]
class Article
{
    #[Column(type: "datetime",
        columnDefinition: "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
        insertable: false,
        updatable: false,
        generated: "ALWAYS")]
    public $created;
}
```

The first time I run `php bin/console make:migration` the correct migration is generated:

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article ADD created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

This works just fine and any DB update now updates `created`. However, this is also where the problems begin. Whenever I make another migration now, it tries to apply the same changes again:

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article CHANGE created created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

How can this be, and does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you very much for your input, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't figure out why this happens. But the solution to this problem is to check if the property in question already exists, and then ignore it when diffing: https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/doctrine-and-generated-columns

**Edit:**

So, the classes used in the blog article above are deprecated and I had to dig a little deeper into Doctrine on how to exclude specific table columns.

I performed the following steps, and it works like a charm:

- Read the official documentation on schema managers: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/schema-manager.html
- Implement a custom `SchemaManagerFactory`
- Implement a custom custom `MySQLSchemaManager` (at least if you use MySQL, that is)
- Make the schema manager use a custom `Comparator`
- Add `schema_manager_factory: doctrine.dbal.default_schema_manager_factory` to my entries in `connections` in `doctrine.yaml`
- Alias `doctrine.dbal.default_schema_manager_factory` in `services.yaml`

Here is some example code to make this more clear.

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                server_version: 8.0.25
                schema_manager_factory: doctrine.dbal.default_schema_manager_factory
```

```yaml
services:
    doctrine.dbal.default_schema_manager_factory:
        class: App\Service\Doctrine\CustomSchemaManagerFactory
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL80Platform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\DefaultSchemaManagerFactory;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaManagerFactory;

final class CustomSchemaManagerFactory implements SchemaManagerFactory
{
    private readonly SchemaManagerFactory $defaultFactory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->defaultFactory = new DefaultSchemaManagerFactory();
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function createSchemaManager(Connection $connection): AbstractSchemaManager
    {
        $platform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
        if ($platform instanceof MySQL80Platform) {
            return new CustomMySQLSchemaManager($connection, $platform);
        }

        return $this->defaultFactory->createSchemaManager($connection);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL\CollationMetadataProvider\CachingCollationMetadataProvider;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL\CollationMetadataProvider\ConnectionCollationMetadataProvider;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySQLSchemaManager;

final class CustomMySQLSchemaManager extends MySQLSchemaManager
{
    public function createComparator(): Comparator
    {
        return new CustomComparator(
            $this->_platform,
            new CachingCollationMetadataProvider(
                new ConnectionCollationMetadataProvider($this->_conn),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL\Comparator;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\TableDiff;

final class CustomComparator extends Comparator
{
    public function compareTables(Table $fromTable, Table $toTable): TableDiff
    {
        $diff = parent::compareTables($fromTable, $toTable);
        
        # Your custom logic here!

        return $diff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine sees that your actual column has a default value while none is defined in its mapping's `options` (ignoring your `columnDefinition`). Thus, it decides it needs to generate an ALTER migration, and when doing so it does take into account your `columnDefinition`.

Set `options: ["default" => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"]` in the column attributes:

```php
#[Entity]
class Article
{
    #[Column(type: "datetime",
        columnDefinition: "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
        insertable: false,
        updatable: false,
        generated: "ALWAYS",
        options: ["default" => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"])]
    public $created;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're only changing entries in this table through Doctrine, you can use [Doctrine lifecycle events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html) to keep created/updated timestamp fields up-to-date.

Comment: That is a good explanation, but sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: @CunningFatalist In that case, there's probably another difference between your columnDefinition and the column's configuration. Try removing your columnDefinition and generating a new migration. It should match your existing columnDefinition, just without ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. If it doesn't, copy the migration's definition into your columnDefinition (adding ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP). I suspect you may need to change the column's type from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME. If that solves it, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: If I remove the `columnDefinition` a new migration just gives me `ALTER TABLE article CHANGE updated_at updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL`.

Comment: @CunningFatalist Looks like you're close then! You need to change your columnDefinition to use DATETIME, not TIMESTAMP.